# Calculate Elapsed Time from One Column

Tags: sql, sql-server

Have an old SQL 2000 DB... Want to see difference of time elapsed from same column based on having two separate values in another column.

```
DECLARE @Now DATETIME,
    @Yesterday DATETIME,
    @StartTime VARCHAR(16),
    @EndTime VARCHAR(16)
SET @StartTime = '01:00:00AM'
SET @EndTime   = '11:59:00PM'
SET @Now = GETDATE()
SET @Yesterday = DATEADD(dd, DATEDIFF(dd, 0, @Now), -1) 
select EventTime, Description, EventID
from EventLog
WHERE   EventTime BETWEEN @Yesterday + ' ' + @StartTime
                  AND     @Yesterday + ' ' + @EndTime
          AND     EventID in (1200 ,1201)
          AND     Description LIKE 'Lane _ Full PE%'
```

[image]

Would like to see the elapsed time SUM from `EventID` 1201 - 1200 as`TimeFull`
Would then like to show this against a 10 hour day and see the Percentage of what we call call `Downtime%`
Lets say SUM was `2:00:00` we would divide by `10:00:00` to show the below

[image]

### ---------------------------------

---

Heres what I see after running the answer

[image]

Answer (score 0):

```
select
    cast(sum(TimeFullInSeconds) / 3600 as varchar(2)) + ':'
     + right('0' + cast(sum(TimeFullInSeconds) % 3600 / 60 as varchar(2)), 2) + ':'
     + right('0' + cast(sum(TimeFullInSeconds) % 60 as varchar(2)), 2) as TimeFull,
     /* assumes same day */
     100 - sum(TimeFullInSeconds) * 100 / datediff(ss, @StartTime, @EndTime) as "Downtime%"
from (
    select datediff(ss, EventTime,
               (
               select min(EventTime) from EventLog l2
               where l2.EventTime > l.EventTime
                   and l2.EventID = 1201
                   and Description like left(l.Description, 6) + ' Full PE%')
               ) as TimeFullInSeconds
    from EventLog l
    where EventID = 1200 and Description like 'Lane _ Full PE%'
) t
```

I have no idea about your business rules here but you'll clearly making some kind of assumption that no two "full" and "clear" events will ever overlap across different lanes. You also seem to assume that the larger window will  span only properly paired events. I'm going with those assumptions.

It seems to me that it's likely better to calculate the time from "full" to "clear" and then deduct that percentage from 100. Doing it that way also makes it easy to match the events up based on lane number. If you don't like it that way then you can easily revert to the old method. Based on the sample date it would appear that the match on description text is redudant. Perhaps your data is actually more complicated.

http://rextester.com/DAFR66165

Comment: Can not get to execute

Comment: Also need to not only look for EventID 1200 and 1201. There are other conditions that trigger one of these events. I only want to look for them if `Description LIKE 'Lane _ Full PE%'`

Comment: Hey @shawnt00 I posted a pic under my original post. Its what I get from running the script

Comment: Obviously you're dealing with more than ten hours of data.

Comment: More than 10 hours of data? I don’t think that’s the case and I may have explained the question incorrectly. I wanted to have the sum of (EventID=1201 - EventID=1200) divided by 10 to show the percentage of time the lanes were “down” during a 10 hour day.

Comment: Down time is the complement of up time, right?: I already addressed that. If you would like my help them you'll have to provide more feedback.